# Return filtered collection of results

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I am trying to return a collection of objects based on the following:

I have three public classes

- `ObjectA`
- `ObjectB`
- `ObjectC`

`C` is a child of `B`, and `B` is a child of `A`.

I need to get a collection of `ObjectC`, when they exist as part of a `B` and `A` object.

This is what I have so far:

```
#region setup

private ObjectADao objectADao;

public void Init()
{
    objectADao = new ObjectA();
    objectADao.SqlMapper = SqlMapper;
    objectADao.AfterPropertiesSet();
}

#endregion

 ICollection<ObjectA> objectACollection = objectADao.FindAll(1000);
 var objectAwithObjectB= objectACollection.Where
 (p => p.objectB != null && p.objectB.Count > 0);
//ICollection<ObjectB> = objectAwithObjectB....
```

At this point I Have a collection (`objectAwithObjectB`) that are of `Object` A type, but only if they contain an `ObjectB` on them.

That is were I have gotten stuck. I now need to get a collection of `ObjectB` types, from the above collection of `A` types. (so I can eventually get to the `C` types).

`ObjectB` and `ObjectC` do not have their own DAO set up, and can only be obtained through `ObjectA`. I can't seem to get a seperate collection of `ObjectB` at this point...

I hope this makes sense. I am still fairly new, so please be gentle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to select properties on objects. You project them to different collections, in this case, from A to B to C. See below.

```
IEnumerable<ObjectB> projectionToCollectionOfObjectB = objectAwithObjectB.Select(x => x.ObjectB);

IEnumerable<ObjectC> projectionToCollectionOfObjectC = projectionToCollectionOfObjectB.Select(x => x.ObjectC);
```

Comment: Yes another +1 for understanding the question... And I am very close now.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
objectACollection
.Where(p => p.objectB != null && p.objectB.Count > 0)
.SelectMany(objA => objA.ObjectB)
```

This will give you a flattend IEnumerable